# Tinymce: загрузка изображений на сервер через frontend

Tags: frontend, tinymce

Хочу сделать загрузку изображения с ПК на сервер через frontend.

На данный момент изображения грузятся с интернета, но без выбора изображения с ПК.

Как это реализовать или может есть лучше вариант чем Tinymce?

```
     tinymce.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements: "news-content",
        theme: "modern",
        language: 'ru',

        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
              ],
       toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
       toolbar2: "responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code",

     });
```

[image: Пример загрузки изображения]